# compact in the product topology

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I am going to check if $\{f \in X: |f(t)|<1 \text{ for all } t \in[0,1]\}$ is compact in the product topology $X = \mathbb R^{[0,1]}$.

I suspect that this would not be compact since it may not be a closed set.
Does anyone give me some hints to deal with this problem? Thank you.

Comment: $\mathbb R^{\mathbb R}$ is not a Euclidean space (meaning Heine-Borel does not apply), and not metrizable; are you sure compact implies closed?

Comment: By some results in weak topology, I understand that we can solve this problem by showing that it is closed and pointwise bounded.

Comment: You may be right; I don't know enough in that respect.

Comment: I think the constant functions $f_n(t)=1-1/n$ form a sequence without a cluster point. A cluster point of $(f_n)_n$ can only be the constant function $1$. Maybe you meant $f(t)\le 1$.

Comment: The set is not closed in $X$, and $X$ is Hausdorff, hence it is not compact.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed it suffices to show that your set $A = \{f \in X: |f(t)| < 1 \mbox{ for all } t \in [0,1]\}$ is not closed in $X = \mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}$, because $X$ is Hausdorff (a product of Hausdorff spaces is Hausdorff) and a compact subset of a Hausdorff space is closed.

One way to see it is not closed: the sequence of (constant) functions $f_n(t) = 1 - \frac{1}{n}$ are in all in $A$, and converges pointwise to the constant function $1$, which is not in $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint 1: the set is not closed, so it's not compact.

Hint 2: if the condition is $|f(t)|\le 1$, then the set is homeomorphic to $[-1,1]^{[0,1]}$ which is …